# Javascript: "Deprecated"

Tags: javascript

[image: Screenshot of message]

I am new in learning Javascript and as I was following the tutorial I found that console.log(name); got (name) struck through in such a way claiming it is "Deprecated".

If there is an explanation on what that means or what I should do to remove that strike, I would be really thankful.

Comment: In a browser environment, the global variable `name`  refers to `window.name`. It is unlikely you intended that. Instead *define* your variable in a local scope before referencing it. In a global scope, avoid `name`.

Comment: @trincot There is `var name = '';` before the `console.log()`.

Comment: "Deprecated" means that it still works but is no longer supported and may break in future versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you used `var name = ...`, TypeScript thinks you are referring to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), which TypeScript considers deprecated. You can fix this error by:

1. Use a different variable identifier, like `anotherName` -

```js
var anotherName = 'Bob'

console.log(anotherName)
```

2. Move the code inside a function. -

```js
(() => {
  var name = 'bob'

  console.log(name)
})()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is due to the fact that a 'loose' variable in a browser, declared with `var`, outside of a function is just going to end up pointing to:

```
window.name
```

And `window.name` has a special meaning, and is indeed deprecated.

It's a quirk of the language. If you didn't intend to create the variable in a global scope, you might be better off just declaring it in a function.

This will not have the same problem:

```
function main() {
   const name = 'Foo';
}
main();
```

Generally it's a good idea to avoid creating any global symbols unless you explicitly intend to.

Comment: I can't find information about window.name being deprecated in the web.